# Get percentages of larger group

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

The query below is kind of an ugly one so I hope I've got it spaced well enough to make it readable.  The query finds the percentage of people that visit a given hospital if they are from a certain area.  For instance, if 100 people live in county X and 20 go to hospital A and 80 go to hospital B the query outputs.  How the heck is this sort of thing done?  Let me know if I need to document the query or whatever I can do to make it clearer.

```
hospital A 20
hospital B 80
```

The query below works exactly like I want it to, but it give me thinking:  how could this be done for every county in my table?

```
select  hospitalname, round(cast(counts as float)/cast(fayettestrokepop as float)*100,2)as percentSeen
from
(

SELECT     tblHospitals.hospitalname, COUNT(tblHospitals.hospitalname) AS counts, tblStateCounties_1.countyName,
                          (SELECT     COUNT(*) AS Expr1
                            FROM          Patient INNER JOIN
                                                   tblStateCounties ON Patient.stateCode = tblStateCounties.stateCode AND Patient.countyCode = tblStateCounties.countyCode
                            WHERE      (tblStateCounties.stateCode = '21') AND (tblStateCounties.countyName = 'fayette')) AS fayetteStrokePop
FROM         Patient AS Patient_1 INNER JOIN
                      tblHospitals ON Patient_1.hospitalnpi = tblHospitals.hospitalnpi INNER JOIN
                      tblStateCounties AS tblStateCounties_1 ON Patient_1.stateCode = tblStateCounties_1.stateCode AND Patient_1.countyCode = tblStateCounties_1.countyCode
WHERE     (tblStateCounties_1.stateCode = '21') AND (tblStateCounties_1.countyName = 'fayette')
GROUP BY tblHospitals.hospitalname, tblStateCounties_1.countyName

) as t 
order by percentSeen desc
```

EDIT: sample data
The sample data below is without the outermost query (the `as t order by` part).

The countsInTheCounty column is the (select count(*)..) part after 'tblStateCounties_1.countyName'

```
hospitalName      hospitalCounts      countyName      countsInTheCounty
st. james          23                 X               300
st. jude           40                 X               300
```

Now with the outer query we would get

```
st james  0.076 (23/300)
st. jude  0.1333 (40/300)
```

Comment: "Looping" should in most cases be like nails on a chalkboard. There is most certainly a way to solve this using county name as an additional grouping, could you show a few rows of sample data, so we know how you got to 20 / 80?

Comment: sure, edits are below main block of query.

Comment: Didn't I answer this question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11086155/61305

Comment: @beaker i'm not familiar with `coalesce` and i wasn't all that sure how it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my guess. You'll have to test against your data or provide proper DDL + sample data.

```
;WITH totalCounts AS 
(
  SELECT StateCode, countyCode, COUNT(*) AS totalcount
  FROM dbo.Patient GROUP BY StateCode, countyCode
)
SELECT 
  h.hospitalName, 
  hospitalCounts = COUNT(p.hospitalnpi), 
  c.countyName, 
  countsInTheCounty = tc.totalCount, 
  percentseen = CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2), COUNT(p.hospitalnpi)*100.0/tc.totalCount)
FROM 
  dbo.Patient AS p
INNER JOIN 
  dbo.tblHospitals AS h
  ON p.hospitalnpi = h.hospitalnpi
INNER JOIN 
  totalCounts AS tc
  ON p.StateCode = tc.StateCode
  AND p.countyCode = tc.countyCode
INNER JOIN 
  dbo.tblStateCounties AS c
  ON tc.StateCode = c.stateCode
  AND tc.countyCode = c.countyCode
GROUP BY 
  h.hospitalname, 
  c.countyName, 
  tc.totalcount
ORDER BY
  c.countyName,
  percentseen DESC;
```